# Transform-origin really difficult on negative rotation

Tags: html, css

Im using **tranform: rotate(-90deg)** but the result is difficult to move to its chosen position. I can do it with Javascript but cant get it right with transform-origin. Please note that only the initial height is known, while the char-length of the object could vary. Here is a js-fiddle version: 
Code:

```
transform-origin:cente -100% ?
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u6yzutw5/2/

Answer (score 3):

You need a combination of rotation and translate

hover to translate

```css
.base {
  position:relative;height:200px;width:200px;background:yellow;margin:50px;
  }

.element {
  display: inline-block;
  position:absolute;top:0;left:0;
  background-color: red;
  }

.base:hover .element {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%) translateY(-100%);
  transform-origin: top left;
  }
```

```html
<div class="base">
  <div class="element">my text</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks (a stack) for the education. Obi Wan has taught you well